# Electron blank page in dev mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server

When my electron app starts, I only see a blank page.
The weird thing is, that the code haven't changed. Now, even when switching back to an old commit, the problem occurs. There are no error messages. Neither on the main thread nor on the renderer thread.

In the first place, I thought it is related to my new m1max MacBook Pro. But I tested the project, that was previously running on an Intel Mac mini, on an Intel MacBook Pro and also got only a blank page.

The strange thing is, that it is working as expected when the app is packaged. The blank page only occurs, when in dev mode.
Dev mode is using `webpack-dev-server`.

The `app.html` is loaded and I also see some code is executed. The container for the component handling some redux stuff is also called. The `render` function of the component itself, is not called. Not sure, what is happening ...

As there is no error message, it's very hard to get feet on the grounds.
Can someone give me some guidance to track the issue down?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with breakpoints or perhaps just inserting a `console.log('im here')` statement at a strategic point in your code and when shown in your console,  move it to another strategic point further down in your code? That way, you can test each section of your code executes. Quick and dirty little tricks like that should begin to build a picture of the problem for you. Let us know how you go.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, tried this strategy. This is how I figured out, that the render function gets never called. But I am not exactly sure in which order things are executed and where the execution ends